# Can not get the expected json out put from input values

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am trying but can not succeed to get my expected json output, Here is my code:

my html

```
 <div class="form-field">

<input type='text' class='name' value="" >
<input name="" id="title" type="text" value="" size="40" aria-
  required="true" class='value'><input type="button" value="convert" 
 id="convert"/><br>
<input type='text' class='name' value="">
<input name="" id="title" type="text" value="" size="40" aria-
 required="true" class='value'>

</div>
```

my js:

```
var $index=1;
 function convert(){

 var  $namevalue=[];

  $('.name').each(function () {
                    $namevalue.push($(this).val());
                });





 //   $namevalue=  $('.name').val();
 for(var i=0; i<$namevalue.length; i++){
//       
    $('.value').attr("name",$namevalue[i]); 
  }



 }
// var $index=1;
 $('#convert').click(function(){
 $index++;
 convert();
 });
```

output of above code:

```
{"height":["blue","24"]}
```

HTML view:
[image]

But my expected output is like this:

```
{"color":"blue","height":27}
```

How can i achieve this, please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

declare $namvevalue as an object `var  $namevalue={}`. Then for each .name use its value as a key and next input val as value.
Also note your html as multiple elements with same id, you should not do that. use different id for each element.

```js
var $index=1;
 function convert(){

 var  $namevalue={};

  $('.name').each(function () {
                $namevalue[$(this).val()] = $(this).next('input').val();
            });





 //   $namevalue=  $('.name').val();
 for(var i=0; i<$namevalue.length; i++){
//       
$('.value').attr("name",$namevalue[i]); 
  }

console.log($namevalue);

 }
// var $index=1;
 $('#convert').click(function(){
 $index++;
 convert();
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="form-field">

<input type='text' class='name' value="" >
<input name="" id="title1" type="text" value="" size="40" aria-
  required="true" class='value'><input type="button" value="convert" 
 id="convert"/><br>
<input type='text' class='name' value="">
<input name="" id="title2" type="text" value="" size="40" aria-
 required="true" class='value'>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the index parameter of [`.each`](https://api.jquery.com/each/) to access the `.value` field with the same index. You'll also have to change `namevalue` to an object instead of an array as you expect an object as the output.

e.g.

```js
function convert() {

  var namevalue = {};

  var $vals = $('.value');
  $('.name').each(function(index) {
    namevalue[$(this).val()] = $vals.eq(index).val();
  });

  return namevalue;
}

$('#convert').click(function() {
  var namevals = convert();
  console.log(namevals);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-field">

  <input type='text' class='name' value="">
  <input name="" id="title" type="text" value="" size="40" aria- required="true" class='value'>
  
  <input type="button" value="convert" id="convert" /><br>
  
  <input type='text' class='name' value="">
  <input name="" id="title" type="text" value="" size="40" aria- required="true" class='value'>
  

</div>
```